# running playframework in background on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, playframework

how can I run a playframework with activator on a amazon ec2 in background? I want to leave the ssh session and server should continue running.

tried this

```
activator "~ run"
```

and

```
activator "~ run" &
```

in both cases server will shutdown when I close the ssh session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to below URL for Remote SSH Sessions and Processes Running After Disconnection.

http://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/

It will definetly resolve your problem. If it does't work then please reply back.

Comment: which one should I use

Comment: Felix, Try one by one i would say because some of our services create problem on server when we closed the session. In that way you need to check with multiple solutions.